# How to find hyperlinks in a word document?

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, ms-word

I'm working on a VB 2015 and I have a problem.
I want to find hyperlinks in a word document containing a paragraph with several words containing hyperlinks. How can I find all the hyperlinks and list them in a text file or textbox?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim wa As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
        Dim wd As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
        Dim wp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph
        wa = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wa.Visible = False
        wd = wa.Documents.Add
        wp = wd.Content.Paragraphs.Add
        wp.Range.Paste()
        wd.SaveAs("F:\sample.docx")

        Dim colHyperlinks As String = wd.Hyperlinks.ToString

        For Each objHyperlink In colHyperlinks
            TextBox1.Text = objHyperlink.TextToDisplay
        Next

        wa.Quit()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: First issue I see is you define a string for hyperlinks, hyperlinks ***is a collection*** in which there could be more than one item... Then you loop through that string which you shouldn't because it's a string, not a list or collection.

Comment: You can notice that I copied a text from webpage then I pasted it by the code into a word document and I want to find the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment's above, you are declaring a `string` type on a `Word.Hyperlinks` ***collections*** object. Therefore you would only ever get one string and not any others. Please see code below, comment's on what it does...

**Note: Code tried and tested**

```
'returns a collection of links, not a string
Dim colHyperlinks As Word.Hyperlinks = wd.Hyperlinks()
```

This code below is just a `LINQ` statement to get all hyperlinks into a `List(Of String)`. You can loop through if you want and then add them to the `Textbox` if you wish...

```
'get all the hyperlinks
Dim arr As List(Of String) = (From hl As Word.Hyperlink In colHyperlinks Select hl.TextToDisplay).ToList()

'show the url's
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr)
```

Or in just one line if you wish...

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, (From hl As Word.Hyperlink In colHyperlinks Select hl.TextToDisplay).ToList())
```

Comment: return some errors and the first one is that: Type 'Word.Hyperlinks' is not defined.

Comment: That error is because you didn't import the namespace.. add this to top of class: ***Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop*** if it was there, you do not need to provide the name spaces like you are...

Comment: I did it but it does not return the hyperlinks, it returns the words only. about yesterday, I meant 1 AM, you know I was sleepy. :)

Comment: The words are not urls or hyperlinks, they are words without hyperlinks

Comment: I don't know why.. but I got only words.

Comment: Do you want me to write the whole code now to see the error?

Comment: I put it but it doesn't appear. this link is the screenshot.https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9tVv.png